# Most efficient Pybullet.getBasePositionAndOrientation vector conversion

Tags: python, pybullet

What is the best way to convert the orientation from

`pybullet.getBasePositionAndOrientation`

to a vector in xyz axis representation in python?
I could only find limited documentation  so far on this issue, thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

SciPy has a [`Rotation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html) class which I find very convenient when working with orientations/rotations.  Among some other things, it makes conversion between different representations pretty easy.

PyBullet returns the orientation as a quaternion.
I assume with "xyz axis representation" you mean what in SciPy is called a "rotation vector" (i.e. "a 3 dimensional vector which is co-directional to the axis of rotation and whose norm gives the angle of rotation").
Given this, the code for converting would look as follows:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

_, pybullet_orientation = pybullet.getBasePositionAndOrientation(...)

rot = Rotation.from_quat(pybullet_orientation)
rotvec = rot.as_rotvec()
```